# Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both locations. Can't open Spyder

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I have no idea what I'm doing.

MacOS Version 10.13.4 and Python 3.7.3

I had anaconda installed and was using spyder fine, but I thought I'd install spyder-terminal using command `pip install spyder-terminal` because I thought that's how I'd get the terminal to show? Anyways now when I try opening spyder, I get this error:

```
objc[1685]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (0x117d8e270) and /anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.dylib (0x11fabda80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 90, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

I tried uninstalling anaconda and then re-installing/updating and re-installing spyder, but I'm still unable to open. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) With this command `pip install spyder-terminal`, you broke your Anaconda installation. After reinstalling, please don't install spyder-terminal like that but using the instructions present in its [Readme](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal#installation) for conda.

Comment: I have the same issue and resolved by referring the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032540/opencv-cv2-imshow-is-not-working-because-of-the-qt/60032783#60032783)