# OpenCV cv2.imshow is not working because of the qt

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, opencv

I am having a problem that I can not use `cv2.imshow()` because of following error message

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
>
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Last Macbook I was using initially did not have QT so I have no idea how should I deal with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same issue after updating `opencv - python to 4.2.0.32`.

Uninstall `opencv-python` and install the lower version (e.g `pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25`) solves this issue.

Comment: Worked for me when I reinstalled with `pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30`. 
This issue seems to only be associated with version `4.2.0.32`

Comment: For `opencv-contrib-python` users, version `4.1.0.25` doesn't exist, so version `4.1.2.30` would be better, like said by @NeilGraham