# Two sets of Qt binaries used by both opencv and pyqt

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt5

I'm running a script running both `PyQT5` and `cv2` and got the message

```
You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "/Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: cocoa, minimal, offscreen, webgl.
```

Therefore I followed the instructions of the answer of this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032540/opencv-cv2-imshow-is-not-working-because-of-the-qt): I uninstalled open -cv and tried `pip install opencv-python==4.1.0.25` but got this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python==4.1.0.25 (from versions: 3.4.8.29, 3.4.9.31, 3.4.9.33, 4.1.2.30, 4.2.0.32, 4.2.0.34)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```

I then installed `pip install opencv-python==4.1.2.30`. This time, the script could be run but I still get the following warning:

```
objc[1151]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11dda55c0) and /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x11f3d9540). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1151]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11dda5638) and /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x11f3d95b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1151]: Class QCocoaApplicationDelegate is implemented in both /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11dda5340) and /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x121f6a030). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1151]: Class QNSApplication is implemented in both /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11dda52f0) and /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x121f6a080). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1151]: Class QCocoaMenuLoader is implemented in both /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11dda52a0) and /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x121f6a1c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1151]: Class QNSOpenSavePanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x11dda5480) and /Users/.../localpckgs/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x121f6a350). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

If it helps, I have the following packages installed:

```
Package         Version
--------------- --------
cycler          0.10.0
decorator       4.4.2
imageio         2.8.0
imutils         0.5.3
kiwisolver      1.2.0
matplotlib      3.2.1
networkx        2.4
numpy           1.18.5
opencv-python   4.1.2.30
pandas          1.0.4
Pillow          7.1.2
pip             20.1.1
pyparsing       2.4.7
PyQt5           5.15.0
PyQt5-sip       12.8.0
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2020.1
PyWavelets      1.1.1
scikit-image    0.17.2
scipy           1.4.1
setuptools      41.2.0
shiboken2       5.15.0
six             1.15.0
tifffile        2020.6.3
```

What should  I do to get rid of the warnings?

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this? I have similar messages trying to run a simple pySide2 script under Anaconda on macOS but I don't have cv2 at all, at least I can not find any trace of it.

Comment: Dear @uhoh. I don't remember solve this back then. What I can tell you is that I would adise you not to use anaconda and create a virtual environment for each of those project. In time you are dealing with the project you have to activate the environment. Then install manually each of the package that you need (once). Try this: it could solve the problem. If it did solve it let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy advice! You are right this project only needs a few libraries, so I will give this a try and let you know if anything interesting (good or bad) comes of it.